# Why React-Router-Dom Outlet does not display the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

I have a component that holds the four different components

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      <div className='flex h-screen overflow-hidden'>
        <div className="md:block hidden fixed top-[25%] ml-2 opacity-80 hover:opacity-100">
          <AdminLinks />
        </div>
        <div className="w-3/4 overflow-auto">
          <div className='h-full p-4'>
            <Main/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='w-1/4 overflow-auto'>
          <Status/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Header (*which does not have a navigation links only in mobile*)

UserLinks (*inside of this it uses the reusable side navigation component*)

```
const AdminLinks = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {userLinks.map((nav) => (
        <SideNav
          key={nav.id}
          id={nav.id}
          link={nav.link}
          icon={nav.icon}
          title={nav.title}
          classname={props.classname}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Main (*in this component it should display the children component I specified in the route*)

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full flex flex-col justify-start ml-4 px-4">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and Status.

In the App component

```
import CoursesAdmin from './components/administrator/CoursesAdmin'

function App() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [isLog, setisLog] = useState(false);

  const routes = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      // Displayed when user is not authenticated
      isLog ?
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />}>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
        :
        <Route path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="courses" element={<CoursesAdmin />} />
        </Route>
    )
  );

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={routes} />
  )
```

I initialized the `createBrowserRouter` and created a `routes` element. The problem is when I click the side navigation it does not display the component inside of the Main rather it throws a "page not found" error.

When I clicked the specific nav of side navigation it should render the path and element provided to it in the inside of the `Main` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with where you are rendering the `Outlet`, but you do have some anti-patterns in your implementation.

- You should not conditionally render routes. Render all routes and use a proper route guard to protect specific routes.
- Pass the `setIsLog` state updater to the `Login` component so it can update the local `isLog` state when a user logs in.
- Pass `isLog` to `ProtectedRoute` so it can handle protecting its sub-routes.

  ```
  export default function App() {
    const [isLog, setIsLog] = useState(false);

    const router = createBrowserRouter(
      createRoutesFromElements(
        // Displayed when user is not authenticated
        <Route path="/">
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setIsLog={setIsLog} />} />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isLog={isLog} />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="courses" element={<CoursesAdmin />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      )
    );

    return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
  }
  ```
- Update `ProtectedRoute` to consume the passed `isLog` prop and redirect to `"/login"` if user is unauthenticated.

  ```
  const ProtectedRoute = ({ isLog }) => {
    if (!isLog) return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;

    return (
      <>
        <Header />

        <div className="flex h-screen overflow-hidden">
          <div className="md:block hidden fixed top-[25%] ml-2 opacity-80 hover:opacity-100">
            <AdminLinks />
          </div>
          <div className="w-3/4 overflow-auto">
            <div className="h-full p-4">
              <Main />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="w-1/4 overflow-auto">
            <Status />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
  ```

[image: Edit why-react-router-dom-outlet-does-not-display-the-component]